# Structs Action class execute method always returns null. Struts 1.3.10

Tags: java, struts1

I'm upgrading our application from an old version of struts to the latest '1' version: 1.3.10.
Now, our code that attempts to process the Action is always getting back a null forward object. I attached the struts source code, and it looks like it ALWAYS returns null.  Prior to upgrading our code worked fine and the forward object was populated when it returned.

```
    forward = super.processActionPerform(request, response, action, formInstance, mapping); 
    return (forward);
```

Now, here's the **Struts code** for processActionPerform:

```
protected ActionForward processActionPerform(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, Action action, ActionForm form,
    ActionMapping mapping)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        return (action.execute(mapping, form, request, response));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return (processException(request, response, e, form, mapping));
    }
}
```

As you can see, this calls the Action execute method.  Below is the Struts execute method code, which you can see always returns null.

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {
    return null;
}
```

I'm wondering if I need to change to use a different Struts class or method to get this to work.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `action` should point to an instance of a **subclass** of `Action` that **overrides** `execute()`.

Comment: No, cannot do that.  It is the Struts class 'RequestProcessor' that calls Action.execute - I have no control over that.  Struts should be able to handle this by itself without me having to write a sub-class. It worked perfectly before with the exact same code - only difference is a later version of Struts.

Comment: I don't understand. You're showing Struts code, which is not relevant; you need to show *your* code, *your* configuration, etc. which is what will *actually* be executed. All you're showing us is code that returns `null`, and it would do that regardless of the S1 version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Ericbn is actually correct - my apologies, Eric.  Yes, I needed to override the execute method in my Action classes.  They currently override 'perform', which was removed from the Action class (formerly deprecated).
Thanks!
Paul